# How to escape non-standard (invalid) HTML tags?

Tags: javascript, angular

I get a response from API that might contain HTML tags and I need to render those tags and I use angular directive `[innerHTML]` and it works perfectly, for the most part, the problem starts when the string is something like this:

`Test string, I am saying <hello>`

`[innerHTML]` treats `<hello>` as a valid HTML tag and the output on the screen is something like this:

`Test string, I am saying`

`<hello>` is not a standard HTML tag and if there is a non-standard HTML tag in the string I want to escape those tags and this should be the output:

`Test string, I am saying <hello>`

Any library to accomplish this task, I want to know if there is any pre-existing solution for this?

Comment: @lusc partially, you shared how to escape tags, but the main question is how to detect non-standard html tags without writting my own parser or something?

Answer (score -1):

Quote the character `<` in front of hello as `&lt;`.

Comment: The question is asking how to do that programatically

Comment: Can not believe that someone asks for something which can be answered with a browser in less then 10 seconds. https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace

Comment: They want to change only **invalid** tags. So `<p>Hello <hello></p>` should be converted to `<p>Hello &lt;hello></p>`. A simple replace is insufficient.

Comment: @Quentin exactly, I want to detect non-standard HTML tags, What I really want is if there is any prebuilt solution else I have to write my own parser for this

Comment: @ceving Thank you for the response but a simple character response is insufficient, first I need to detect if the tag in the string is a standard HTML tag

Comment: @RabinGaire Here you find a list of all tags: https://html.spec.whatwg.org/